# it’s pretty much preachin

Tags: vocabulary

> Joe: Yeah, but, as a rule I usually don’t bring up the topic of
>   vegetarianism with people. I mean…
>
> Kristin: Yeah, I, I don’t like to either, actually.
>
> Joe: Yeah, **the way I figure it**, if the person’s already a vegetarian,
>   then **it’s pretty much preachin’** to the choir.

1) Does "the way I figure it" mean "from my perspective and from where I stand; from my point of view; the way I see it"?

2) Why did the author use the -ing form of the verb "It is pretty much preaching to the choir" in the context above?

Source: A.J. Hoge, Effortless English, Real English Conversation

Comment: About question #2: is there another form of the verb that you think might be appropriate here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"The way I figure it" is a Midwestern American colloquial expression to mean "I think". "The way I see it" is another variation on "I think", so you are correct.  Another example:

> **"The way I figure it,"** the farmer drawled, tilting back his his hat, "if we work together we can get in all the harvest before the autumn rains start up in earnest."

"Preach to the choir" is a common English idiomatic expression:

> **[Preach to the choir](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/preach-to-the-choir)** (v): to try to persuade people who already agree with you

The -ing form makes it a [participle](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/participle.htm) or a [gerund](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/gerund.htm) phrase -- in this case it's not clear which -- that pairs with the existential "it".  This is probably the most common way this idiom appears.

> "You could go talk to my parents," she said, "but since they're old-school Liberals from way before I was born, encouraging them to vote for your candidate is **preaching to the choir**.  They're going to vote for her anyway."

In your example "pretty much" is another way to say "mostly", or "just", depending on the context.

> The mechanic sighed and shook his head.  "This old heap is **pretty much** a rolling wreck.  Have you thought about buying a new car?"

Comment: Common in UK English too, edited accordingly

Comment: @JamesK  Cambridge dictionary labeled it "American English" so I wonder if it's an import?  Same difference either way, I suppose.

Comment: Preaching to the converted is common in the UK. I have met some very ungodly choir members.

Comment: Even the converted can benefit from preaching. Just saying.